# How to plot a 3d solid generated by revolving a curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, asymptote, tikz-3dplot

[image]

I have this curve `(0,0) parabola (1,1)` and I would like to generate 3d plots where this curve is revolved around the x-axis, y-axis, x=a, y=b, x=c, and y=d. Is this possible? How can I do it? If it's relevant, here is the rest of the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Stealth](-0.5,0)--(2,0);
\draw[-Stealth](0,-0.5)--(0,2);
\draw[thick, color=black, name path=xaxis](0,0)--(1,0);
\draw[color=black] (0,2) node [anchor=north west] {$y$};
\draw[color=black] (2,0) node [anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw[thick, name path=curve] (0,0) parabola (1,1);
\tikzfillbetween[
    of=curve and xaxis
  ]{color=gray!30};
\draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt](1,0)--(1,1);
\draw[color=black] (1,0) node [anchor=north] {$a$};
\draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt](0,1)--(1,1);
\draw[color=black] (0,1) node [anchor=east] {$b$};
\draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt](1.5,0)--(1.5,1.5);
\draw[color=black] (1.5,0) node [anchor=north] {$c$};
\draw[dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt](0,1.5)--(1.5,1.5);
\draw[color=black] (0,1.5) node [anchor=east] {$d$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Parametric plot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337707/plotting-a-3d-surface-plot-of-a-surface-of-revolution  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/surface-of-revolution  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173602/pgfplots-3d-creating-a-filled-solid-of-revolution  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125624/tikz-surface-of-revolution-of-a-hyperbolic-trajectory

Answer (score 8):

This is an Asymptote drawing for revolutions around some axes. Note that they have almost the same code. I choose the view `obliqueZ` from z-axis, so we can see things in the the Oxy plane as usual in the plane (you may not want to draw Oz, just remove `draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--6*Z,Arrow3());`. The red generating curve `g` is the parabola `y = x^2` is parameterized as `(t,t^2,0)`.

**1.** The paraboloid is a revolution using `g` as generating curve, center `O`, and axis `Ox`:

```
revolution mypara=revolution(O,g,X);
```

[image]

Full code: copy to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and click **Run**

```
unitsize(1cm);
import graph3;
import solids;
//currentprojection=orthographic(2,1.5,.5,zoom=.95);
currentprojection=obliqueZ;
currentprojection.zoom=.95;
size(8cm);
real a=1.8, b=a^2;
real c=2.5,d=4.5;
triple A=(a,0,0), B=(0,b,0);
triple C=(c,0,0), D=(0,d,0);
// the (red) parabol curve on the XY-plane
triple paraXY(real t){return (t,t^2,0);}
path3 g=graph(paraXY,0,a);
draw(g,red+1.2pt);

// use one of the following revolutions
//revolution mypara=revolution(C,g,Y); // around x=c
//revolution mypara=revolution(D,g,X); // around y=d
//revolution mypara=revolution(O,g,X); // around y=0
revolution mypara=revolution(O,g,Y); // around x=0
draw(surface(mypara),yellow+opacity(.7));
//draw(mypara,blue,orange);

label("$a$",A,S); label("$c$",C,S);
label("$b$",B,W);
label("$d$",D,W);
draw(A--(a,b,0)--B^^C--(c,d,0)--D,dashed+gray);
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),-2*X--6*X,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),-5*Y--6*Y,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--6*Z,Arrow3());  // you may not want to draw Oz
```

**2.** The same code, only change `X` to `Y` to get revolution around `Oy`

```
revolution mypara=revolution(O,g,Y);
```

[image]

**3.** The same code, for revolution around `x=c`

```
revolution mypara=revolution(C,g,Y);
```

[image]

**4.** Last, for revolution around `y=d`

```
revolution mypara=revolution(D,g,X);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

This is a quick modification of an answer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619390/how-can-i-draw-the-surface-fx-y-x2y2-like-my-picture). It's a 2d drawing using isometric perspective. The equations of parabola and ellipses are calculated by hand. The ellipses are very simple if you know about isometric perspective (the axes ratio is `sqrt(3):1`). The parabola was obtained as an envelope of the family of 'horizontal' ellipses.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  axes/.style={thick,-latex},
  cylinder/.style={right color=blue!80,left color=white,fill opacity=0.6},
  paraboloid/.style={left color=magenta!80,fill opacity=0.6},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% axes x,y
\draw[axes]  (30:3)  -- (210:3) node [left]  {$x$};
\draw[axes]  (150:3) -- (330:3) node [right] {$y$};
% cylinder, back
\draw ({-0.75*sqrt(6)},0) arc (180:0:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)}) --++ (0,2.25)
                          arc (0:180:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)}) -- cycle;
% paraboloid, back
\draw[paraboloid] ({0.25*sqrt(51)},2) parabola bend (0,-0.125) ({-0.25*sqrt(51)},2)
  arc ({180+atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{-atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)});
% axis z
\draw[axes] (0,0) -- (0,4) node [above] {$z$};
% paraboloid,  front
\draw ({0.25*sqrt(51)},2) parabola bend (0,-0.125) ({-0.25*sqrt(51)},2)
  arc ({180+atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{360-atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)});
% cylinder, front
\draw[cylinder] ({-0.75*sqrt(6)},0) arc (-180:0:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)})
                      --++ (0,2.25) arc (0:-180:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

**Update:** A modification, suggested by Sebastiano. I changed all the hidden lines for dashed ones. This improves the visibility but increases a bit the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  axes/.style={thick,-latex},
  cylinder/.style={right color=blue!80,left color=white,fill opacity=0.7},
  paraboloid back/.style={left color=magenta!80,fill opacity=0.4},
  paraboloid front/.style={left color=white, right color=magenta!80,fill opacity=0.4},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% axes x,y
\draw[thick]        (30:3)    -- ({0.75*sqrt(6)},{0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw[thick,dashed] (210:1.5) -- ({0.75*sqrt(6)},{0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw[axes]         (210:1.5) -- (210:3) node [left]  {\strut$x$};
\draw[thick]        (150:3)   -- ({-0.75*sqrt(6)},{0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw[thick,dashed] (330:1.5) -- ({-0.75*sqrt(6)},{0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw[axes]         (330:1.5) -- (330:3) node [right] {\strut$y$};
% cylinder, back
\draw[dashed] ({-0.75*sqrt(6)},0) arc (180:0:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)});
% paraboloid, back
\fill[paraboloid back] ({0.25*sqrt(51)},2) parabola bend (0,-0.125) ({-0.25*sqrt(51)},2)
  arc ({180+atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{-atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw ({-0.25*sqrt(51)},2)
  arc ({180+atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{-atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)});
% axis z
\draw[thick,dashed] (0,0) -- (0,{2.25-0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw[axes] (0,{2.25-0.75*sqrt(2)}) -- (0,4) node [above] {$z$};
% paraboloid, front
\fill[paraboloid front] ({0.25*sqrt(51)},2) parabola bend (0,-0.125) ({-0.25*sqrt(51)},2)
  arc ({180+atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{360-atan(1/sqrt(17))}:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)});
\draw[dashed] ({0.25*sqrt(51)},2) parabola bend (0,-0.125) ({-0.25*sqrt(51)},2);
% cylinder, front
\draw[cylinder] ({-0.75*sqrt(6)},0) arc (-180:0:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)})
                      --++ (0,2.25) arc (0:-180:{0.75*sqrt(6)} and {0.75*sqrt(2)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I suggest to use also the dotted or dashes line. Thus it is visible the effect of the profondity.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are probably right. It's easier this way, working only with opacity to show the visibility. If I draw the dashed lines I'd need to obtain the points where the visibility changes, e.g., where the axes cut the cyilinder generatrices. But I'll take a look at it.

Comment: My it was only a humble suggestion. My best regards. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, you were right, it looks better :-)

Comment: You can see the depth of the paraboloid better. I'm glad that you have agreed with my thoughts. Congratulations on everything and on your skill.